# difference of behaviour between dygraphs.js and dygraphs.min.js

Tags: javascript, minify, bundling-and-minification, dygraphs

I am using the `dygraphs` library in `javascript`. I needed to debug something so I switched from the minified version to the non-minified one but I then got different behaviours.

Changing nothing in my code except

```html
<script src="/node_modules/dygraphs/dist/dygraph.min.js"></script>
```

into

```html
<script src="/node_modules/dygraphs/dist/dygraph.js"></script>
```

In my case, `dygraphs.min.js` accepts extra fields in the `option` object used in

```js
let g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById(divName),
    data,
    options
);
```

whereas `dygraphs.js` fails with the message

```
invalid option the_name_of_my_extra_field
```

Is that expected ?

Comment: Did you check the constructor? Also are you using same version? because, ideally, `min.js` and `bundle.js` should have same behavior

Comment: they are both in the folder of dygraphs that was directly loaded from `npm install dygraphs` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dygraphs so assuming they are the same yes.

Comment: Can you create a snippet? You can use following link to load it via CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/dygraph

Comment: Ok will try that and comment here when done so

Comment: Please try using these links: [debug version](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g391rhqz/5/) and [minified version](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/us4e5Lry/1/). Bpth work fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended. The debug build [warns on invalid options](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/27cee3f7233fbbbeed31f0cf03ea81bf92555b18/src/dygraph-options.js#L339) because these are likely to be mistakes (misspelled option names, etc.):

```
> new Dygraph(div, data, { made_up_option: false });
Uncaught invalid option made_up_option
```

These checks are stripped out of the production build to reduce code size and improve performance.

Comment: OK noted thank you. I actually liked that I could pass in anything and it would only use what was relevant. Could I warn that it does not know some fields but still allow the graph to be built using the options it does know ?

Comment: For debug builds, you could hack in your own version of the warning: `g.attributes_.warnInvalidOption_ = (optionName) => { /* ... */ }`. That will work for `updateOptions` but not for options passed to the constructor.